# Flag rows based on different column values for a single column sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to flag cases where a patient has listed multiple diseases.

[image]

I can not think of how to summarize that variation(in Diz column, there are more than 10 combinations) in a 'case when' statement, I believe the rest part would be partition by id.. but need help figuring out that first part of case when statement.

I am trying to modify following:
case sum(case when Diz in ('FLU1'
, 'FLU2'
, 'FLU3'
, 'FLU4'
, 'FLU5'
, 'FLU6'
, 'FLU7'
, 'FLU8'
, 'FLU9'
, 'FLU10'
, 'FLU11'#so on...
') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Id) when 2 then 1 else 0 end flag

But it flags similar values. Can anyone help or provide tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way uses `min()` and `max()` as window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(diz) over (partition by id) = max(diz) over (partition by id)
             then 0 else 1
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic can be expressed simply and efficiently with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Diz <> t1.Diz) AS flag
FROM tablename t1
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the exists function and the code snippet!